# PHP get selected value of select form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm using Laravel and currently creating a form, where users can first choose a category, and then choose a relating subcategory.

A category has an id and a name, a subcategory has an id and a name, as well as a parent_id (so that's the id of the parent category).

Now I try the following:
The user can pick a category, after he did that, the second `select` appears and the user can choose the subcategory from the subcategories that belong to the parent category (and only those!).

Therefore, the view gets all categories and all subcategories from the controller.

Then, for the categories I did this:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('category') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="category" class="col-md-4 control-label">Kategorie</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select>
                                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category['id'];?>">{{$category->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

And for the subcategories I have the same, just with subcategories:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('subCategory') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="subCategory" class="col-md-4 control-label">Unterkategorie</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select>
                                        @foreach($subCategories as $subCategory)
                                            <option value="<?php echo $subCategory['id'];?>">{{$subCategory->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Now the question is: What I need to do is (in the subcategory foreach) a `@if` and check for the value of the chosen `option` of the `category select` and then check `if($subcategory->parent_id == $chosenOptionID)`, to say it in pseudo code. How can I do this? I don't want to send the form or something, before somebody didn't choose the subcategory as well.... Of course, I maybe could send an ajax request to the controller whenever a category is chosen, then check the value of the option in the controller and send back the id. But this would cause very much traffic and would propably not be the best solution, so I'd like to do this only, if I don't get a better way to do....

PS: The question is not about hiding the subcategories when no category is chosen, thats basic js, I know how to do that. I only want to know, if it is possible to read the value of the `category select` while form is not sent yet.

**EDIT**: I now tried the AJAX thing but there seems to be a little error...
What I changed:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('subCategory') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="subCategory" class="col-md-4 control-label">Unterkategorie</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="subCategorySelect">

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

The select is now empty and has an ID. Then in the same file I have the following JS:

```
<script>
    $().ready(function(){
        $('#categorySelect').change(function(){
            var selectedOption = $('#categorySelect').find(":selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/getSubCategories',
                data: {'id': selectedOption},
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#subCategorySelect').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

`/getSubcategories`route points to the following function in my controller:

```
public function returnSubCategories(Request $request){
        $subCategories = Subcategory::where('parent_id', '=', $request->id);
        foreach($subCategories as $subCategory){
            echo "<option value='$subCategory->id'>$subCategory->name</option>";
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work.. The ajax request is defintely sent on selecting an option, as well the correct id is sent. But somehow nothing is outputted... Any ideas why?

Comment: in your `<input` add `'selected'`

Comment: and @foreach is not in a php tag :P

Comment: @Blueblazer172 Í have no input to add selected, and what should that do? and `@foreach` is blade syntax, the template engine of laravel

Comment: ah ups never worked with lavarel. you still interested how to do it with "normal" php ?

Comment: @Blueblazer172 sure, if there is a way to do it wihout sending lots of ajax requests then I'd be pleased to know

Comment: okay but i dont know how to implement it in lavarell, maybe it's not working there :P so sshould i post an awnser on how i used it ?

Comment: @Blueblazer172 basically, every php will work with laravel as well, it's just more readable using blade, so feel free to post an answer

Comment: i dont want to get -rep because not answering exactly your question... but i'll do if you want

Comment: if the thing you provide works then its all fine, I didn't ask for explicitly use laravel/blade syntax, normal php is cool and I still can "convert" it, its easy, basically, the `@foreach` thing is exactly the same as `<?php foreach(){}?>`, just have the `@` in front of end a `@endforeach` at the end (because there are no `{}`, same with every other control structure from php

Comment: You need to work with Javascript. Because your page is already loaded. If the subcategory select is on a other page that you can pass the Post data and filter only subcategories with same parentID. Thats if i understand your question properly :P

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani correct, if it would be on another site it would be easy... Javascript itself is okay, but how? jQuery is as well no problem... ofcourse, I could potentially read the selected option with javascript over a id I give to the `category select`, but what then? I could set something like a invisible input (`type=hidden`) with that value, but that one I can't read with php as well...

Comment: i dont work with Laravel. But what i would do with Symfony 2 is: make a different controller that select the subcategorie from you database or whatever :P pass the selected categoryID with Ajax to the controller and select all Subcategories with the same ParentID(CategoryID) .. return that and show it in the selected subcategory

Comment: @nameless so i have an example on how to handle it with php, but only for one selected field... and then store the value to the db. but i dont think it's what you asked.. but ill post it if it helps anyway to understand

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani so you kinda do like I said with ajax, would be my "last possibility", if I don't find another way 
'll have a look

Comment: Its because PHP is already loaded on the page. You basically asking if you can run PHP on a loaded page without javascript if i'm correct. Don't think thats possible. Would make my life easier tho :P

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani yeah, you're right, would make a lot thinks easier.. Then I'll propably try with AJAX

Comment: There is a great bundle for Symfony called JSRoutingBundle.. This allows you to route easy with Ajax through your controllers.. Maybe you can find a similar one for Laravel.

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani I would have propably tried something like (Pseudocode follows):  $().ready(function(){
        $('#categorySelect').change(function(){

        });
    }); and in there something like that:  $.ajax({
                url: '/getSubCategories',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                   subcategorySelect.html(data);
                }
            }); 
and then in the controller just returning the subcategories that match the given data/id (that I forgot in my example)

Comment: Thats correct. That is what i also would do. Goodluck. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working with AJAX. This is my initial `subCategorySelect`.

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('subCategory') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="subCategory" class="col-md-4 control-label">Unterkategorie</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="subCategorySelect">

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

The select is now empty and has an ID. Then in the same file I have the following JS:

```
<script>
    $().ready(function(){
        $('#categorySelect').change(function(){
            var selectedOption = $('#categorySelect').find(":selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/getSubCategories',
                data: {'id': selectedOption},
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#subCategorySelect').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

`/getSubcategories`route points to the following function in my controller:

```
public function returnSubCategories(Request $request){
        $subCategories = Subcategory::where('parent_id', '=', $request->id)->get();
        foreach($subCategories as $subCategory){
            echo "<option value='$subCategory->id'>$subCategory->name</option>";
        }
    }
```

And it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you sure it is working correctly ? You have a type GET but you are posting data.

Comment: Maybe i've got it wrong.. it seems like your Request is handeling it :P

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani yeah, its the request handeling it, as well, this function (`returnSubCategories`) is completely independ from the function later processing the posted form data

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you understand how it works with php anyway for **one** selected option:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="country">Country:<span>*</span></label>
    <select name="country" type="text" class="form-control" id="country">
        <option value="">--Country--</option>
        <?php
        include "../db/db.php"; //db-connection cause i want to load a country list
        $sql = "SELECT id, country_name FROM apps_countries ORDER BY country_name ASC";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) { //check if an entry is there
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { //get the values from the db

                //now this is the part you have to implement in your script
                if(isset($_POST["country"]) && $row["id"] == $_POST["country"]) { //check if country isset so if the user selected something

                    $optionSelected = "selected='selected'";

                } else{

                    $optionSelected = "";

                }

                //your foreache loop goes here / add the value that is selected here
                /*@foreach($categories as $category)
                        <option value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>">{{$category->name}}</option> // get the associative array with "" and change it to $category["id"]
                @endforeach*/

                /**for my attempt it was this
                                {the id like as your category[id]}   {set the selected here inside the option tag}
                                                    ↓                  ↓                     */
                $countrySet = "<option value='" .$row["id"]. "' ".$optionSelected.">".$row["country_name"]."</option>";
                echo $countrySet;
            }
        }
        $conn->close();
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What I'm wondering about is: How can you access `$_POST["country`]` if you didn't submit the form before?

Comment: @nameless look for AJAX this it the only way to load it if not submitted

Comment: this will only work if you submitted the for youre absoluetly right

Comment: maybe someone else is posting an answer to handle it with ajax